# Why does the exception "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" keep appearing even after changing the -xmx VM option?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, heap-memory, ram

I'm on a 64 bit OS on a Mac with 8GB of RAM. I need to allocate 2.9GB to some arrays of bytes in a program written in Java (I simply declare them). Since by default you can't use more than 1GB of heap space for running a java project, you need to specify in the VM options if your program needs more. I am on IntelliJ Idea, so I do this by going on `Help` -> `Edit Custom VM Options` and then changing the `-xmx` field. But no matter how many MBs I allocate, the program can't run due to this exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`, as if I didn't change anything in the VM options. The PC has enough free RAM to contain arrays of 2.9GB when running the program.

Comment: What did you set the heap size to?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't consuming more than 2.9GB? And what are you passing as the `-xmx` argument?

Comment: Are you 100% sure about not allocate more than 2,9GB, one tip is know what type of data did you use, because for example int type allocates 4 bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Help` -> `Edit Custom VM Options` is set for IDEA itself but not your program. Set `-Xmx` in `Run` -> `Edit Configurations..` -> `your application` -> `VM options` instead.

Comment: This solved it.